# Static number of rows on rdlc tablix

Tags: winforms, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting

Im binding a tablix on a report viewer (winforms) to a list of car parts, however there will always need to be 50 rows displayed, even if there is no value in all 50 rows.

At the moment, the table is displaying all parts that I add to the database table, however it is not displaying 'non-existant' data rows.

Any ideas how I can display a static number of rows even when no data is present?

Hope this makes sense and thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this with the 'lookup' function.

1. Create a new dataset with the numbers 1 to 50.
2. Set your table to use this dataset so that it always has 50 rows.
3. Add an ID row to your initial car parts data so that they can be matched up with rows in the new table.
4. Use the lookup function in an expression to populate the fields in the table. It would look something like this:

   =Lookup(Fields!ID2.Value, Fields!ID1.Value, Fields!CarPartName.Value, "OriginalDataset")

You could put this in an 'iif' statement to show blanks for the values that don't have a corresponding ID.